# Why must a free throw shooter starting out cold, have an 80% make rate on their way to 90+%

Tags: probability, combinatorics, optimization

Our fantastic free throw shooter, Stephanie Spicy, ends her season with her free throw percentage above 90%, as she expects. However, the season didn't start out so great, she went 0 for her first 8. She got nervous, because an oddity in her contract stated she had to be *exactly* 80% accurate at some point in her season in order to get her bonus. However, she breathed a sigh of relief because when she simulated out the season in Excel (being a fellow math geek), she noticed she always crossed 80% exactly at some point, so long as she played her typical season with over 300 attempts.

**Why, in mathematical terms, did she always cross 80% exactly?**

One possible example scenario below, but adding additional misses only moves the 80%, never eliminates it. On the other hand, 70% is sometimes present, and sometimes not.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $a_n$ to be the number of shots made in the first $n$ shots attempted. Consider the quantity $b_n = 5 a_n - 4n$. Note that $b_n \geq 0$ iff $\frac{a_n}{n} \geq \frac{4}{5}$.

Now note that $a_{n + 1} - a_n \in \{0, 1\}$. Therefore, $b_{n + 1} - b_n \in \{1, -4\}$.

In particular, this means that $b$ can only increase one at a time. And $b_n$ is always an integer. So if $b_n$ ever goes from negative to nonnegative, it must have been zero at some point. At this point, we will have an exact 80% record.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that this argument works for any fraction of the form $\frac{k-1}{k}$. And indeed, we can see $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{2}{3}$, and $\frac{3}{4}$ in the example spreadsheet as well...

Comment: Apologize for being a math newbie, but what does $b_n represent in the formula and how would it ever be negative?

Comment: @NickHeidke Let's say we've attempted 5 shots and made only 3. Then $n = 5$ and $a_n = 3$. Just plugging into the formula gives us $b_n = 5 a_n - 4n = 5 \cdot 3 - 4 \cdot 5 = -5$. In a sense, it's a way of representing how close we are to an 80% record.